# Trying to create (math) matrix with brackets using div elements with a table inside. Table does not stay inside div

Tags: html, css, matrix, html-table

I've been trying to create a math-type matrix using div elements with the correct CSS for them (`display: table;`, `display: table-row;`, and `display: table-cell` as appropriate).  There is a 3×3 grid of div elements acting like table cells.  The actual matrix of numbers is a table in the center element.  The two side columns hold images for the side brackets of the matrix, with the 4 corners holding the top and bottom and the 2 sides having the straight vertical piece.  I do this so that the straight vertical piece can stretch to fill its entire container, and any size matrix can be represented.  Also, it will be possible to animate the matrix growing or shrinking, something that I couldn't figure out how to do by using a table instead of div's for the bracket pieces.  The top-center and bottom-center "cells" are empty.

Here is the code.  It's just a test page so I put the CSS in the `head` section.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A</title>
        <style>
            .divTable{
                display: table;
            }
            .divTableRow{
                display: table-row;
            }
            .divTableData{
                display: table-cell;
            }
            .imgBracketTop{
                width: 14px;
                height: 7px;
            }
            .imgBracketMiddle{
                width: 14px;
                height: 100%;
            }
            .imgBracketBottom{
                width: 14px;
                height: 5px;
            }
            .tableInnerMatrix{
                border-collapse: collapse;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .tableInnerMatrix td{
                width: 1.4em;
                height: 1.4em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="divTable">
            <div class="divTableRow">
                <div class="divTableData"><img src="left-bracket-top.png" class="imgBracketTop"/></div>
                <div class="divTableData"></div>
                <div class="divTableData"><img src="right-bracket-top.png" class="imgBracketTop"/></div>
            </div>
            <div class="divTableRow">
                <div class="divTableData"><img src="left-bracket-middle.png" class="imgBracketMiddle"/></div>
                <div class="divTableData" style="border: 1px solid orange;">
                    <table class="tableInnerMatrix" style="border: 1px solid blue;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>11</td>
                            <td>-5</td>
                            <td>-8</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>24</td>
                            <td>-3</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>-18</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>9</td>
                            <td>-9</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>6</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="divTableData"><img src="right-bracket-middle.png" class="imgBracketMiddle"/></div>
            </div>
            <div class="divTableRow">
                <div class="divTableData"><img src="left-bracket-bottom.png" class="imgBracketBottom"/></div>
                <div class="divTableData"></div>
                <div class="divTableData"><img src="right-bracket-bottom.png" class="imgBracketBottom"/></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the table in the center div has its first line at the bottom of its div and then all the rest of it extends straight down.  I put borders around the table and the div to show exactly where they both 
are:
[image: Table going below its div]
I experimented by replacing the table with things like `1<br/>2<br/>3` and only the top line stayed where it should have.  All the other things (the 2 and 3 in this case) went below.

The culprit is the `height: 100%;` in the two images for the middle of the brackets (the `imgBracketMiddle` class).  If I remove that, then everything goes where it should, but that prevents me from being able to stretch that image for arbitrary size matrices.

The only solution I could come up with is to wrap the inner table inside another 1×1 table, like this:

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;"><tr><td>
    <!-- Existing table code goes here -->
</td></tr></table>
```

If you do that, you get this:
[image: Hacky fix]
which looks pretty good, however it seems like a very non-standard way to fix it and is probably not the best solution to keep in there.  I'm also a bit worried it won't allow smooth animations if I try to change the size of the matrix.  (Actually, this might not even work either just because there's a table in there.. but I will get to testing that once I figure this out.)

Is there a good CSS way to ensure that all of the table goes inside of its div rather than just the first line?

Here's a jsfiddle, but it's even worse on there because it puts breaks between the images and makes the middle images way too big (I used a different image since my bracket ones aren't online):  http://jsfiddle.net/n7hhqp8z/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td class="top-and-left"></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="top-and-right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"></td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bottom row">
      <td class="bottom-and-left"></td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="bottom-and-right"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>


    <style>
    .top-and-left {
      padding: 5px;
      border-top: thin solid black;
      border-left: thin solid black;
    }

    .top-and-right {
      padding: 5px;
      border-top: thin solid black;
      border-right: thin solid black;
    }

    .bottom-and-left {
      padding: 5px;
      border-bottom: thin solid black;
      border-left: thin solid black;
    }

    .bottom-and-right {
      padding: 5px;
      border-bottom: thin solid black;
      border-right: thin solid black;
    }

    .left {
      border-left: thin solid black;
    }

    .right {
      border-right: thin solid black;
    }

    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, using `float: left` on the table itself pretty much fixed everything.  From reading other things, it seems like that's the best thing to do.  However, I still don't understand why this did this.  If I play around with the `height` of the `imgBracketMiddle` class, it just keeps pushing the table up or down.  This is for any kind of height: percents, pixels, I assume all the others too but I didn't try them.